# The setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is not working

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

My `activity_main.xml` gives me an error which says `activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I did `Android 2.2` while unchecking the x on "Create Activity"  so everything was empty and I had to fill it!

Comment: `import yourpkg.R;` in your activity and try

Answer (score 1):

On your project explorer

click on resources,then

click on layout,then

you see a "file_name.xml"  if not rename it to "file_name.xml" by pressing F2 ,

then replace

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout."file_name");
```

dont forget to add

```
import "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME".R;
```

above class decleration

Answer (score 0):

It looks like u have imported android.R instead of that you import your package name else make it as

**setContentView(packgname.R.layout.activity_main);**

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing

```
import android.R;
```

remove this line and then press ctrl+shift+o(for import necessary packages R file)

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse IDE

```
 Porject---->clean>Build Automatically
```

Import packagename.R
by pressing ctr+shift+o